# Proving distribution is reversible condition

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I'm working on the following question:

> Consider an irreducible homogeneous Markov chain over a discrete state space $S$, all of whose states are positive recurrent. Prove that its stationary distribution $\pi$ satisfies the detailed balance conditions (i.e., is reversible) if and only if
>   $$p(x_0,x_1) p(x_1,x_2)\cdots p(x_{n-1},x_n)p(x_n,x_0) = p(x_0,x_n)p(x_n,x_{n-1})\cdots p(x_2,x_1)p(x_1,x_0)$$ for all finite sequences $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n \in S$.

I'm having some trouble even concocting ideas for this. Does anyone have any specific hints or advice?

Comment: I think reversibility applies to a chain, not to its stationary distribution. What is this condition precisely?

Comment: This is known as the Kolmogorov Criterion for time irreversibility.  The first direction of your *iff*, i.e. $ \text{ Detailed Balance Conditions } \longrightarrow \text{Kolmogorov Criterion}$ is quite easy.  As is the original post is needs some more effort and/or context.